# PHP: Determine action based on time of day

Tags: php, time

I'm sure this is a pretty basic task, but I'm quite new to programming and am a bit confused.

Basically I want to execute a different action based on the time of day. For example, if the time is between 05:00 and 20:00 (8pm), run "scriptA". ELSE, or if time is between 20:00 and 05:00, run "scriptB".

What is the easiest way to do this? I basically want to run one script during the "Day" and the other at "Night".

Thank you!

Comment: Check time of day. If, else.

Comment: Who's day?  Your user's?  Your business's? Your web server's?  Time zones matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if((date("H") > 5) && (date("H")<20) )
{

//run_my_day_script

}

else
{
//run_my_evening_script

}
?>
```

Comment: This would do 6am to 7pm as it lacks an equals check.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the date function.

```
echo date("H:i:s");
```

will display the current time. Get this string. Compare it and use an if/else.

[PHP Date Reference Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Get the hour of the day in a 24 hour format, without leading zeros.

```
$hour = (int)date("G");
```

Then you can do a less or greater that check.

```
if ($hour >= 5 && $hour <= 20)
{
  // Do Something.
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php